# Commerce paypal WPS not convert unsupported currency

Tags: drupal, paypal, drupal-7, drupal-6, drupal-modules

Hi i try to use drupal 7 commerce paypal WPS payment method but my store use BGN - Bulgarian lev currency and when i try to checkout my order with paypal 30BGN in paypal are 30USD. How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PayPal WPS (Payments Standard) module only supports the currencies identified in Paypal's API documentation https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest/currency-codes/.

Since BGN isn't on the list, it falls back to USD.  You can either:
a) patch the PayPal module to support payment transactions in BGN
b) use the Commerce Multicurrency module [https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_multicurrency] to get an actual conversion rate between BGN and a PayPal supported currency you want to transact in.